# Query DOM element + string

Tags: jquery

I have this element `this.$el.parentElement` and I would like to subquery it with an additional class, i.e

```
$(this.$el.parentElement + ".box")
```

This is not working obviously, ss there an elegant way to do this?

Currently I have to query like this:

```
$('#' + this.$el.parentElement.id + ".box")
```

Which is a bit ugly and it might not have id just class then it wont work

Comment: What are you trying to do? `$(this).parent().find('.box')` ? If that is the case, then you are missing a space before `".box"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're attempting to get the `.box` element stored within the `$el.parentElement` then you should use the `find()` method.

```
var $box - $(this.$el.parentElement).find('.box')
```

Your initial attempt is trying to concatenate a string to a jQuery object - which will not work in the manner you expect it to.